# rsuite date range selector- remove 'Ok' button

Tags: reactjs, date-range, daterangepicker, rsuite

I am using rsuite for date range selector in my react app, but I don't want the highlighted 'Ok' button.
How can we select a date range without that button?
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2n94.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `oneTap` option for this

```
<DatePicker
  value={value}
  oneTap={true}
/>
```